# How to test http.Redirect target URL in golang

Tags: go, testing

I have set up a http redirect in the go handler, and I'm trying to verify if the target URL is composed as expected.
I'm currently using httptest for relevant unit test.

In the handler:

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s?token=%s", domain, someURL, token)
http.Redirect(w, r, url, 302)
```

The current unit test can only verify the respond code but not the target URL:

```
resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
router.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
assert.Equal(t, 302, resp.Code)
```

I'm expecting something like

```
assert.Equal(t, expectedURL, resp.redirectURL)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assert that the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header is as expected:

```
assert.Equal(t, expectedURL, resp.Result().Header.Get("Location"))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/iaUMkBneNUI

Comment: ```assert.Equal(t, expectedURL, resp.Location)```
this also works as well using http request

Comment: I'm curious as to why the "HeaderMap" is used and not the 'resp.Result().Header["Location"][0]'.   I'm just starting with the framework of httptest and I'm unable to understand why we use "resp.Result().StatusCode", but then use the headerMap instead of the result object again... 

Also, I just received a depreciation warning when trying to use this approach instead of the one I have used... but mine doesn't work and yours does... so I'm very confused.

Comment: @EricL. The answered used a deprecated field.  Use `resp.Result().Header.Get("Location")`